# Chrome Gmail extension does not work in certain circumstances. Why?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, inbox

I'm working on a Chrome extension. When a local PDF file is opened in Chrome, by clicking on the extension icon, it opens a new tab with gmail.com (and compose view) and attaches the opened file to a new email.

With a "normal" Gmail account, it works fine. The problem is, if I use an account with alias senders (e.g. personal and business), the attaching doesn't always happen. Sometimes it attaches the file, sometimes doesn't. If it failes the following error message appers in console: www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:18 Error logged: Error: Failed to find dropzone

What is wrong with the code?

app.js

```
var content = {
init() {
    //this is gmail page
    InboxSDK.load(2, 'sdk_Add-Attachment_df7347fce8').then((sdk) => {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            message: "getFile",
        }, (response) => {
            if (response.file != 'No File Found') {
                sdk.Compose.registerComposeViewHandler((composeView) => {
                    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                        message: "getFile",
                    }, (response) => {
                        console.log("uploaded file", response.file);
                        if (response.file != 'No File Found') {
                            var fileData = content.base64ToArrayBuffer(response.file);
                            var file = new File([fileData], response.fileName, {
                                type: response.fileType
                            });
                            composeView.attachFiles([file]);
                            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                                message: "deleteFile",
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
                sdk.Compose.openNewComposeView().then((composeView) => {
                    console.log("composeView is", composeView);
                });
            } else {
                console.log("No file to add");
            }
        });
    });
},
base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binaryString = window.atob(base64);
    var binaryLen = binaryString.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
    for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
        var ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
        bytes[i] = ascii;
    }
    return bytes;
}
};
$(document).ready(() => {
    content.init();
})
```

background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
if (tab.url.indexOf("file://") != -1) {
    //this is file page
    localStorage.setItem('FileUrl', tab.url);
    console.log('Saved file to be attached', tab.url);
    window.open('https://mail.google.com');
} else {
    alert("Please open tab with url beginning with file:// and try again.");
}
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (request.message == "getFile") {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var fileUrl = localStorage.getItem('FileUrl');
        if (fileUrl != 'undefined' && fileUrl != null) {
            var fileName = fileUrl.split('/').pop();
            request.open('GET', fileUrl, true);
            request.responseType = 'blob';
            request.onload = function() {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(request.response);
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    console.log('DataURL:', e.target.result);
                    const byteString = atob(e.target.result.split('base64,')[1]);
                    const ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
                    const ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
                    for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i += 1) {
                        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
                    }
                    const newBlob = new Blob([ab], {
                        type: 'application/pdf'
                    });
                    sendResponse({
                        file: e.target.result.split('base64,')[1],
                        fileName: fileName,
                        fileType: 'application/pdf'
                    });
                };
            };
            request.send();
        } else {
            sendResponse({
                file: 'No File Found'
            });
        }
        return true;
    } else if (request.message == "deleteFile") {
        localStorage.removeItem('FileUrl');
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of composeView.attachFiles([file]) use this:

```
composeView.getBodyElement().focus();
setTimeout(function() {composeView.attachFiles([file])}, 1000);
```

Or, alternatively:

```
composeView.attachInlineFiles([file]);
```

Comment: Seems to be working, thank you so much! Can you explain why it solves the problem please?

Comment: Before I found this, I noticed, that in a new dialog the input focus is located in the To or Subject fields, not in the main area. When I manually focused the main area and executed my script, everthing worked fine.

I guess when this area is not focused, the dropzone is not available/created yet, so this small hack just triggers some code to create/init it.